# I am having issues with my python code

Tags: python-2.7

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this code. I am new to python, and coding in general. I have looked for other solutions, but for some reason I keep ending up in a loop of pain...

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter the value of the exponent of i."))
y = x / float(4)
z = y-int(y)
#----------------------
if int(z) == 0():
    print "The answer is 1."

if int(z) == 0.25():
    print "The answer is i."

if int(z) == 0.5():
    print "The answer is -1."

if int(z) == 0.75():
    print "The answer is -i."
```

For some reason, everything I try always gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\I_Exp.py", line 6, in <module>
 if int(z) == 0():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: So are you trying to call something here? What is the syntax used to call something? That might be a clue to what the error means.

Comment: () is used to call a fuction, and 0 is an `int` object. I think you should read the basic syntax of Python first.

Answer (score 0):

- The brackets are used to call function or change precedence of operators in python, it's no mean to add () after a constant float point number either change to `int` to a `int`.
- When you want to output a variable in the string, you should use % sign as below, or you could use comma to separate the string and the variable, like `print "the answer is", d`

You could do like this:

```
x = float(raw_input("Enter the value of the exponent of i."))
y = x / 4
z = y-int(y)

if (z == 0):
    print "The answer is 1."

if (z == 0.25):
    print "The answer is %d." % i

if (z == 0.5):
    print "The answer is -1."

if (z == 0.75):
    print "The answer is -%d." % i
```